# Different values when writing and reading floats to binary file

Tags: c++, io

I have a piece of code that writes some floats to a binary file, and later reads them back. The read data is different from the written data.

Why does this happen? Can it be fixed? Here is my code:

```
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main ( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
    float a[3];
    float b[3];
    a[0] = 0.3721548;
    a[1] = 0.3721548;
    a[2] = 0.3475495;

    ofstream file("mlt_data", std::ios::binary);
    file << a[0];
    file << a[1];
    file << a[2];
    printf("write: \t%.7f %.7f %.7f\n", a[0], a[1], a[2]);
    file.close();

    ifstream file2("mlt_data", std::ios::binary);
    file2 >> b[0];
    file2 >> b[1];
    file2 >> b[2];
    printf("read: \t%.7f %.7f %.7f\n", b[0], b[1], b[2]);
    file2.close();
    return 0;
}
```

And this is the output:

```
write:  0.3721548 0.3721548 0.3475495
read:   0.3721550 0.3721550 0.3475490
```

Comment: Examine the contents of the file in your favorite text editor. You are writing decimal representation of your numbers, with 6 digits of precision.

Comment: You "binary" does not make any difference here. You are writing your data using formatted output functuions (operators `<<`), meaning that you are writing it as *text*. Later you read it as *text*. If you want to write/read your data as *binary data*, use binary input/output functions.

Comment: When you write the data out you probably want to add spaces between the numbers to keep them separate.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Yes, I know, if I print only 6 digits they look the same. But the difference isn't only when printing. If I try an equality check, I still get a `false`.

Comment: You are writing your numbers *to the file* with 6 digits of precision. You are rounding at that point, losing extra precision. Of course when you read these rounded numbers back from the file, they don't match the originals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though opening your files in binary mode, when using `>>`- and `<<`-operators, you actually "serialize" your data into a textual representation. When using `<<` on data type `float`, the value it by default rounded to a precision of 6. So you "loose" precision/information while writing, which cannot be reproduced when reading in the textual float representation later. So the difference in your output is due to the fact that you write to files values rounded to 6 digits, while you `printf` the values with a precision of 7.

To demonstrate that this is actually the case, test to set the `<<`-precision to 7 (right before actually writing the values):

```
file << std::setprecision(7);
```

But actually you should write your data in binary format:

```
file.write((const char*)a, sizeof(a));
...
file2.read((char*)b,sizeof(b));
```

Comment: Ah ok. I didn't know about the serialization. Now it makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Using the flag `std::ios::binary` changes how newline characters are written to and read from a file. See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c#Binary_and_text_modes for more details.

It does not change how formatted input and output are written/read.

If you want to retain the accuracy of the numbers, use `ostream::write` and `istream::read`.

```
ofstream file("mlt_data", std::ios::binary);
fire.write(reinterpret_cast<char const*>(a), sizeof(a));
printf("write: \t%.7f %.7f %.7f\n", a[0], a[1], a[2]);
file.close();

ifstream file2("mlt_data", std::ios::binary);
file2.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(b), sizeof(b));
printf("read: \t%.7f %.7f %.7f\n", b[0], b[1], b[2]);
```